# Failure to re-project SpatialPolygonsDataFrame to Equidistant Cylindrical in R (units problem?)

Tags: coordinate-system, r, reprojection-mathematics

I am trying to re-project a shapefile to match the projection and units o Black Marble nightlights data (link below) which comes in a raster with Equidistant Cylindrical projection, units in meters. However, when I do this re-projection, the extent of the shapefile is way, way too big... larger than the entire world. I think this is because the shapefile is originally in decimal degrees, and the nightlights raster is originally in meters. However, I'm not sure how to alter my re-projection process, to fix the problem.

Specifics: my nightlights data has this projection:

```
+proj=eqc +lat_ts=0 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
```

My district shapefile has this projection:

```
+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
```

When I re-project my shapefile (using `spTransform`), the extent of the shapefile becomes:

```
extent : 8911228, 9818899, 2933088, 3389212  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
```

This is FAR, far larger than the extent of my nightlights data, which coves the entire world, with an extent of `-180, 180, -90, 90`. So of course, one can't map them together or extract the nightlights data to the shapefile.

Can anyone advise on how to better do this re-projection? (I also tried reprojecting the raster itself using `projectRaster` -- and precisely the opposite happened, the resulting raster extent was so small as to be a tiny speck within the shapefile.)

Comment: If your night data is 180,90 bounded it is not in the projection you mentioned

Comment: @IanTurton "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0" is a coordinate reference system, not a projection...

Comment: I was just about to ask similar questions to those on your cross-posted version. Probably not a good idea to cross-post like this.

Comment: As @IanTurton suggested, the nightlights data is almost certainly in EPSG:4326 AKA latitude-longitude.

Comment: Sorry, not fully following these comments. Ian, the night data is -180, 180, -90, 90 in Equi Cylin projection. What do you mean by 180,90 bounded? Spacedman, apologies if I broke a protocol, though I'm also not quite following you --- what do you mean by similar questions? Similar to those by Rekyt? All: Why do you doubt that the nightlights data are not in Eq. Cy.? I'm merely going from the projection string embedded in the product, given in the first line of code above.

Comment: Additionally, maybe I'm missing something, but even if the projection string is incorrectly describing the nightlights projection, I still don't understand why the reproject isn't working. I am quite literally using 2 lines of code to project the districts (`districts`) to the same projection as the nightlights (`night2006_DM`): `rstprj_DM <- proj4string(night2006_DM)` and then `districts_DM <- spTransform(districts, rstprj_DM)`. This should work under any nightlights projection, but does not.

Comment: Link to the 2012 nightlights data and the district shapefile here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/icrr9lytnmquolu/AADXURrSOXUxFuwn6yHJoAhba?dl=0

Comment: I think that eqc is mis-applied to some NASA files, I've seen this in the ocean colour too. I'd just override what gets read in, with  nl <- setExtent(nightlights, extent(-180, 180, -90, 90)); projection(nl) <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0" - check it, and move on

Comment: Wow, thank you so much!! This seems to work -- at least, after doing this, I can re-project the district shapefile to match, and they now have reasonable extents, and plot over one another. I've never just assigned a projection like this; I didn't know it was possible, and I never would have thought to question the embedded projection. Thank you so much for telling me this. And thanks everyone else for saying the same!

Comment: Cross-posted unsuccessfully, w/ slightly different wording, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52785774/failure-assigning-polygon-to-equidistant-cylindrical-in-r-or-projecting-equidis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't access your file/s right now, but this happens with some NASA data sets - you can trivially flip between eqc and longlat, it's pure scaling.

For example, down in the Monthly MODISA Mapped products:

```
##oceandata.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/MODISA/Mapped/Monthly/9km/SST
gdalinfo NETCDF:"A20021822002212.L3m_MO_SST_sst_9km.nc":sst
...
NC_GLOBAL#latitude_step=0.083333336
NC_GLOBAL#latitude_units=degrees_north
NC_GLOBAL#license=http://science.nasa.gov/earth-science/earth-science-data/data-information-policy/
NC_GLOBAL#longitude_step=0.083333336
NC_GLOBAL#longitude_units=degrees_east
NC_GLOBAL#map_projection=Equidistant Cylindrical
...
```

Technically Equidistant Cylindrical "eqc", is a map projection in metres:

```
library(raster)
eqc <- "+proj=eqc +lat_ts=0 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
projectExtent(raster(extent(-180, 180, -90, 90), crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"), eqc)
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 10, 10, 100  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 4007502, 2003751  (x, y)
extent      : -20037508, 20037508, -10018754, 10018754  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=eqc +lat_ts=0 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
```

But, the data structures in these files are *identical* to one treated with `extent(-180, 180, -90, 90)` in longlat, so I'd **check it**, but then apply the proper interpretation and move on. :)

I.e.

```
(r <- raster::raster(rgdal::readGDAL('NETCDF:"A20021822002212.L3m_MO_SST_sst_9km.nc":sst')))
#NETCDF:"A20021822002212.L3m_MO_SST_sst_9km.nc":sst has GDAL driver netCDF
#and has 2160 rows and 4320 columns
#class       : RasterLayer
#dimensions  : 2160, 4320, 9331200  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#resolution  : 0.08333334, 0.08333334  (x, y)
#extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : NA
```

See above how the GDAL/raster code sees the extent in longlat, but doesn't know what the crs is?

Now I'm only guessing this applies to your files but I'm reasonably sure it'll work.

```
x <- setExtent(r, extent(-180, 180, -90, 90))
projection(x) <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
```

Comment: Last question -- what are you doing here, with this `raster::raster(rgdal::readGDAL())` line? Why is it that this uncovers the unknown CRS, when the way I looked at it (just simply looking at the CRS listed in the raster) shows the false CRS? Just trying to understand this tool for the future. : ) Thanks!

Comment: I was moving too fast and didn't realize why it didn't work with only raster() ... that weird syntax "NETCDF: ..." is GDAL subdataset syntax, referencing one of multiple variables (sds) in a complex file. At the command line GDAL needs that syntax, and rgdal (being close to GDAL) can use that too. I tried it with raster, but raster ignores GDAL/rgdal and uses the ncdf4 package directly, and it expects an actual file name not this weird sds thing. So, I could  (and should) have used 'raster("A20021822002212.L3m_MO_SST_sst_9km.nc", varname = "sst")`   to get the same result